# CorfFlags warning CF011 about strong name signed even after /force

Tags: c#, .net, partcover, corflags

Im trying to use Corflags to get PartCover running under x64. When I use:

CorFlags.exe PartCover.exe /32BIT+ /Force

i get:
corflags : warning CF011 : The specified file is strong name signed. Using /Force will invalidate the signature of this image and will require the assembly tobe resigned.

without /force i get:

corflags : error CF012 : The specified file is strong name signed. Use /Force to force the update.

On web there appears that others are runnig partcover throught corflags with no problems...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see the problem.  When you use /Force corflags is updating the PE header so that the assembly is x86 (32 bit), however this does invalidate the strong naming and thus you must resign the altered assembly.  That is why you are seeing the warning, but I would bet that corflags is altering the assembly.

By not using /Force then corflags is telling you it won't do something that will invalidate the assembly without you explicitly giving it permission to with the /Force arguement.

Comment: Yea thakns :), i didnt realized that usage of corflags is first set flag on .exe and then normally use .exe

Comment: I also found the message confusing as to whether it was altering the assembly or not - but turns out it was.